# How can I enable bootstrap buttons using javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I'm trying to enable bootstrap buttons for all submit buttons using the code below. However, it doesn't work. What is wrong?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/inc/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button, input:submit, input:button').button()
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did u load the bootstrap css??

Comment: Yes, adding the class 'btn' works fine. However unfortunately it isn't possible to add the class to all submit buttons.

Comment: Did you verify whether your jQuery selector is returning all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]').addClass('btn');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: $('input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], button')